# jQuery .fadeIn flicker caused by browse back / forward

Tags: jquery, caching, flicker

I'm using the following code to fade in images:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.slides_control img').css('display', "none');
    $('.slides_control img').fadeIn(800);
});
</script>
```

However, anytime I browse back/forward, with my links, or the browser's back/forward buttons, I tend to get a flicker. It's random. On initial load it never happens.

So, do I need to set a time out..? Prevent caching..? Or, is there a better method..?

I have also hidden `.slides_control img` in my css file.

Comment: By "flicker" I mean that the image appears for a millisecond before being hidden, and fading in.

Comment: Why don't you use regualr CSS to hide the image, and not a `.load()` handler? Also note you have a mismatched `"` and `'` on `none` in the `.css()` line.

Comment: Hi Jarred, thanks for your response. I do hide the image in my CSS. I fixed the mismatch `"` and "`" but still getting the flicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $p = $('<p><a href="#">Refresh</a></p>').appendTo(document.body);
    $p.find('a').click(function(){
        window.location.reload();
        return false;
    });
    $('.slides_control img').css('display', "none");
    $('.slides_control img').fadeIn(800);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fhF5E/

It does flicker when you click Refresh several times in a row.

Using:

```
.slides_control img {
    display: none;
}

$(window).load(function(){
    var $p = $('<p><a href="#">Refresh</a></p>').appendTo(document.body);
    $p.find('a').click(function(){
        window.location.reload();
        return false;
    });
    $('.slides_control img').fadeIn(800);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fhF5E/1/

I haven't been able to get it to flicker once.

Even this doesn't flicker:

```
<div class="slides_control">
    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"/>
</div>
<script>$('.slides_control img').hide();</script>

$(window).load(function(){
    var $p = $('<p><a href="#">Refresh</a></p>').appendTo(document.body);
    $p.find('a').click(function(){
        window.location.reload();
        return false;
    });
    $('.slides_control img').fadeIn(800);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fhF5E/3/

**EDIT**

After reviewing the actual page that demonstrated the problem, it was discovered that the `display: none` was being applied to the `img` in such a way that on page load, the `display: none` selector was not selecting anything, but then *was* selecting *after* the slider effect was added (on ready).

So...

```
.slides_control img {
    display: none;
}
```

Needs to change to:

```
.slider img {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jarred, thanks again. I tried your answers, but to no avail. I'm going to double-check everything to see if the issue is not being caused by a conflicting script - although from my research, I'm thinking the cached image is being loaded faster than the script has time to execute..

Comment: If css (as in not the jQuery `$.css()` method) is used to `display: none` on the image, it *will not* display even for a millisecond on page load unless there's something else that's overriding it (in your css files, some other Javascript file). If the image is flickering because it hasn't fully downloaded (this doesn't seem likely, but is plausible, I don't know), you can load the image with Javascript in the `window.load` handler and set the `img.load` to add the `click` handler after it loads. Put `style="display: none;"` in the image element markup and see what happens.

Comment: Hi Jarred...I have not been able to resolve :/ Would you mind taking a look at the site I'm working on? If you navigate thru the images so they load, and then try to go back and forth thru those images you'll see the flickr. Yes, I do have it set to `display: none` on my .css stylesheet. Here's the link to the site: http://peteryang.com/v02/image/vartkess-tarbassian-2/ - - Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I see what you're talking about, and the flicker. Look here and you'll see I've disabled some jQuery calls and the image is viewable: http://jfcoder.com/test/fadein.html You've definitely got a lot of conflicting stuff going on. Always remember when debugging to *isolate* down to where the problem is occurring, and *then* start looking at why it's happening.

Comment: I have added the solution the answer in an edit. See here for a demo: http://jfcoder.com/test/fadein_fixed.html (And note that the fix only works on that page, due to the fact each image view loads on a new page, not the same page. So if you attempt to navigate to the next image, you will go back to the real site with the old problem.)

Comment: Jared if I was girl I would kiss you LOL That did it. I'm still learning to debug, thank you for your tip. I love you. Sorry, I'm so emotional right now! lol